# not able to recognize config interface of protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to migrate my protractor tests from JS to TS.
I am not able to assign the type of the protractor config file.

When i try the below:

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';

exports.config: Config = {.....
```

it throws an error as: ***[ts] 'Config' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.***

But i am able to proceed like this,

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';

const _config: Config = {.........};

exports.config = _config;
```

What is the basic thing i am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `tsConfig.json` file ? If so , what is the value of `target`?

Comment: target is set to es5